# At only 550 rep, I can see expanded votes

Tags: bug, voting, privileges

I recently answered a question, which I thought was good, and upvoted it. I came back later and clicked the number, and to my surprise, it shows the votes (up and down). I'm only at 554 reputation, and I thought this was unlocked at 1000. I thought it might have had to do with voting/answering the question, but I can see it for any question.

Pretty sure this is a bug, since the next privilege in my activity page still says `see vote breakdown`, but it's a useful change (intended or not) in my opinion.

I tried searching, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: That's temporary, not a bug, there is a voting experiment going on.